# Sorting array based on Year and Day

Tags: sorting, swift5

I have this function that sorts an array into a two dimensional array based on date, but I want to sort based only on day and year, not the whole date (including hours etc..).

```
    func sortHomeworks() {
    /*
     Sorts homeworks by date
     */
    // First it groups them into a dictionary
    let groupedHomeworks = Dictionary(grouping: recivedHomeworks) { (element) -> Date in
        return element.date!
    }
    // Then it sorts the keys in this new dictionary in reverse order
    let sortedKeys = groupedHomeworks.keys.sorted{$0 > $1} //ReverseSorting
    // add every [Homework] into --> homeworks [[Homework]]
    sortedKeys.forEach { (key) in
        let values = groupedHomeworks[key]
        homeworks.append(values ?? [])
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code which groups your items is:

```
let groupedHomeworks = Dictionary(grouping: recivedHomeworks)
                         { (element) -> Date in return element.date! }
```

To group by just year and day you need to change `element.date!` to produce a key containing just those two values rather than returning the whole date. As this expression returns a `Date` value you can use a `DateFormatter` ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter)) to do this, you could format the date as YY-MM-DD or something similar.